# MessageBroker initialization error in eclipse

Tags: java, xml, spring, apache-flex, blazeds

1. I am configure flex with spring frame work using blaze Ds . 
           download blaze Ds.war file, then i was created web dyanmic project
           in eclipse.
   I was create web application , META-INF,WEB-INF place in web content copy from blazeds.war
   i
   will change service-config.xml file  given below

```
            <services>
                <service-include file-path="remoting-config.xml" />
                <service-include file-path="proxy-config.xml" />
                <service-include file-path="messaging-config.xml" /> 

                <default-channels> 
                <channel ref ="my-amf" />
                </default-channels> 

                <!-- 
                 <destination id="myService" channels="my-amf">
                        <properties>
                            <source>example.Helloflex</source>
                        </properties>
                    </destination>    -->   
            </services>

            <security>
                <login-command class="flex.messaging.security.TomcatLoginCommand" server="Tomcat"/>

            </security>

            <channels>

                <channel-definition id="my-amf" class="mx.messaging.channels.AMFChannel">
                    <endpoint url="http://localhost:8080/flex-test/messagebroker/amf" class="flex.messaging.endpoints.AMFEndpoint"/>
                </channel-definition>

                <channel-definition id="my-secure-amf" class="mx.messaging.channels.SecureAMFChannel">
                    <endpoint url="https://localhost:8080/flex-test/messagebroker/amfsecure" class="flex.messaging.endpoints.SecureAMFEndpoint"/>
                    <properties>
                        <add-no-cache-headers>false</add-no-cache-headers>
                    </properties>
                </channel-definition>

                <channel-definition id="my-polling-amf" class="mx.messaging.channels.AMFChannel">
                    <endpoint url="http://localhost:8080/flex-test/messagebroker/amfpolling" class="flex.messaging.endpoints.AMFEndpoint"/>
                    <properties>
                        <polling-enabled>true</polling-enabled>
                        <polling-interval-seconds>4</polling-interval-seconds>
                    </properties>
                </channel-definition>


            </channels>

            <logging>
                <target class="flex.messaging.log.ConsoleTarget" level="Error">
                    <properties>
                        <prefix>[BlazeDS] </prefix>
                        <includeDate>false</includeDate>
                        <includeTime>false</includeTime>
                        <includeLevel>false</includeLevel>
                        <includeCategory>false</includeCategory>
                    </properties>
                    <filters>
                        <pattern>Endpoint.*</pattern>
                        <pattern>Service.*</pattern>
                        <pattern>Configuration</pattern>
                    </filters>
                </target>
            </logging>

            <system>
                <redeploy>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>

                </redeploy>
            </system>

        </services-config>

        **i was set default channel**

        > `<default-channels> 
                <channel ref ="my-amf" />
                </default-channels> `

        *after i create application-config.xml file , /WEB-INF/spring/application-config.xml*

        > `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
            xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
            xmlns:flex="http://www.springframework.org/schema/flex"
            xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/flex 
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/flex/spring-flex-1.5.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">


                <context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
                <context:component-scan base-package="example"></context:component-scan>
                <flex:message-broker services-config-path="/WEB-INF/flex/services-config.xml"> </flex:message-broker>

         </beans>
        `

    **web.xml**

    > ` <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">



      <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/spring/*-config.xml
            </param-value>
        </context-param>

        <filter>
            <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
            <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
        </filter>

        <filter-mapping>
          <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
          <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>

        <listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
        </listener>

        <listener>
            <listener-class>flex.messaging.HttpFlexSession</listener-class>
        </listener>

        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>messagebroker</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                <param-value></param-value>
            </init-param>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>messagebroker</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/messagebroker/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>`



    **java class file **

    > ` package example;

    import javax.xml.ws.ServiceMode;

    import org.springframework.flex.remoting.RemotingDestination;
    import org.springframework.flex.remoting.RemotingInclude;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;


    @Service("HelloFlexService")
    @RemotingDestination(channels={"my-amf"})
    public class Helloflex {

        @RemotingInclude
        public String sayHello(String name)
        {
            return "hello".concat(name);
        }

    }`
```

**after i start server it can 404 error will come, i will send my error details **

```
>   
>     SEVERE: Error thrown during MessageBroker initialization
>     java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: ASYNC_MESSAGE_FILTERS_ELEMENT_CHILDREN
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using the wrong versions of jars as Spring-Flex-Integration tries to initialize a field it expects but the version you provieded doesnt offer.
Have a look at this post ... here someone is having similar problems:
http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/flex/90301-nosuchfielderror-async-message-filters-element-children

Comment: **blazeds-common-4.0.0.14931.jar  , spring-flex-core-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar,aopalliance-1.0.jar, spring-integration-core-1.0.3.RELEASE.jar,  then spring jar 3.1.2 versions ..... I using same blazeds jars any find version appropriate jar for this applications **

Comment: Ok ... so I am using the same versions, just that I use Spring in 3.1.3.RELEASE and 4.0.0.RELEASE. But I also remember that I had to manaually deploy the jars as they were not available in any public repo. So eventually you deployed the wrong version? The size of my working blazeds-common-4.0.0.14931.jar is 95.864 Bytes and of my blazeds-core-4.0.0.14931.jar is 685.390 Bytes ... so perhaps you should check this first.

Comment: Ya.. I check it out fully my blazeds-common-4.0.0.14931.jar is 95,864  bytes and  blazeds-core-4.0.0.14931.jar is 685,390  bytes ,blazeds-proxy-4.0.0.14931.jar is  66,253  bytes , blazeds-remoting-4.0.0.14931.jar is 18,852  bytes .. so mostly same what you have jar list , so can i add any  other .......